# Why are keyframes occurring when adjustments are made with transform?

Tags: transforms

Im making adjustments to with transform over an image in the video sequence and the nothing would perceivably happen until i scrub through and its as if random keyframes have been positioned
its very irritating what is happening?

Many thanks,

J

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure Automatic Keyframe is disabled in the timeline as shown below as the red circle.
[image]
When enabled, a keyframe will be added for anything you move, rotate, or scale.